# Logic related to sessions

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an requirement to show users a pop up when there is one minute left to session expires time. Suppose session expiration time is 5 minutes and I need to show a pop up that "Your session will expire in next one minute" please click here if you want to continue otherwise click cancel. So, if user clicks ok, time should again refreshed automatically and if cancelled then no need to do any thing .
For this I have done something like this in my Shared folder in Layout

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () { myTimer() }, 240000);
function myTimer() {
    var r = confirm("Session will expire in a minute. will you like to continue working?");
    if (r == true) {
        var _Id = $("#Id").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../Home/ResetUser",
            data: "{'User_ID':'" + _Id + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Data == 'Done') {
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        window.clearInterval(myVar);
    }
```

But I have one problem and that is I do not have the same layout derived in all the pages. Some modules have different layout and some pages do not need any layout.So, I need to keep that script running differently for different layouts or the pages which do not use the layouts.

Will it work fine if I keep the script differently for different layouts?
Also Suppose I have logged in and I set a session variable. Now time is set to 5 minutes 
and user come to home page which is not using the layout  where I kept the above script.
I have the script added differently in this page and script function time starts..

but then user went to another page then session time will refreshed?
and I have to load my above script function on that page?
Am I doing the right things.

Comment: FYI, it's named ".NET", not "dot net". Also, you don't need it in the title, since it's in the tags.

Comment: Slight logical flaw with your script - if the user is away from keyboard when the confirm appears and they return 10 minutes later - if they click 'Yes' to continue working, this will not refresh their session, as they will have already timed out.  Not sure a JS confirm is the best choice here - you may also need some functionality to take action if the session does expire (e.g. redirect to login).

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can write your script in **_viewstart.cshtml** file.

This will be executed for each request irrespective of the Layout page you are using

*but then user went to another page then session time will refreshed? and I have to load my above script function on that page?*

Yes when you user refresh the page or request the server again the session time will be reset.

This is the one way to achieve your requirement.